# Vuetify - File upload convert to base64 format

Tags: vue.js, file, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have file input for image

```
<v-file-input show-size v-model="img" @change="upload(img)" label="Image"></v-file-input>
```

I'm trying to read it and convert the file into base64 string

```
    upload(img) {
        console.log('img', img)

        var file = img.files
        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            console.log('RESULT', reader.result)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)

    },
```

I can't get my RESULT to run... please HELP!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this error because a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)'s [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) takes a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) as parameter.

You are currently passing it `undefined` (check by running `console.log(file)`), because `img` is a
[File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) (which is a Blob), and it doesn't have a `files` property.

Passing it the file should work:

```js
     // ...
     reader.readAsDataURL(img)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this function to convert file to base64

```
const getBase64 = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    });
};
```